# attr of multiple img id show in line

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

In my code i have 5 images in li tag and first li having activeimg class .
i have one button also .I want when i click the button the current li should remove the activeimg class to next li and the attr('id') of that first li img should show and again when click the next li it also should remove activeimg class to next li and the attr should show along with first li's img attr('id').

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').on('click', function() {
    var tagname = $('.activeimg img').attr('id');
    $('.activeimg').removeClass('activeimg').next('#allimg li').addClass('activeimg');
    $('#resultdiv').html(tagname).val;
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_card ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_card ul li img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.menu_card ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.menu_card ul li.activeimg {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="menu_card">
          <ul id="allimg">
            <li class="activeimg"><img id="one" src="imges/img1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img id="two" src="imges/img2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img id="three" src="imges/img3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img id="four" src="imges/img4.jpg"></li>
            <li><img id="five" src="imges/img5.jpg"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2" style="margin-top: 350px;">
        <div class="pull-right clickme">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/> Like
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center" id="resultdiv">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In my code i can only see the img attr of current li's .
In my case it always replace the previous one like when click second li it shows the two and one is erased . I want it to be shown like one,two,three,four,five not individual attr.

Suggest me if i have to checkbox method or something else. thanks in advance

[My CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/tanmndz/bL7xeLp0/)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the code. Be more specific about your requirement.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tanmndz/605x3rdq/ this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Fiddle I tried this for the click handler:

```
var tagname = $('.activeimg img').attr('id');

$('.activeimg').removeClass('activeimg').next('#allimg li').addClass('activeimg');

if (tagname) {
    var result = $('#resultdiv');
    var text = result.text().trim();

    if (text) {
        text += ',';
    }

    result.text(text + tagname);
}
```

That seems to give the behaviour you requested.

I left those first two lines unaltered, the rest builds up the text. The only thing that makes this look complicated is the need for commas between the ids.

Using the DOM to store state like this (reading and writing the element text) is not ideal but I tried not to deviate too far from your original code. You could, for example, have an array holding the list of Liked images and then generate the element text from that rather than relying on the old text.

Comment: it is the solution I was looking for.Thank you,

Comment: if you don't mind i have another small problem.
After click the last eement it is black.Can it be stayed at last elemnt only?